# Heroku cant detect Procfile (Pycharm)

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, procfile

I have also tried using the echo command and i have it on github also but for some reason it wont be detected.
Here is what i have inside `Procfile` `"worker: python main.py"

Here is the build log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.8.5
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting certifi==2020.6.20
         Downloading certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
       Collecting chardet==3.0.4
         Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
       Collecting idna==2.10
         Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
       Collecting oauthlib==3.1.0
         Downloading oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
       Collecting PySocks==1.7.1
         Downloading PySocks-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting requests==2.24.0
         Downloading requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
       Collecting requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
         Downloading requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
       Collecting six==1.15.0
         Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
       Collecting tweepy==3.9.0
         Downloading tweepy-3.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
       Collecting urllib3==1.25.10
         Downloading urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
       Installing collected packages: certifi, chardet, idna, oauthlib, PySocks, urllib3, requests, requests-oauthlib, six, tweepy
       Successfully installed PySocks-1.7.1 certifi-2020.6.20 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.10 oauthlib-3.1.0 requests-2.24.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 six-1.15.0 tweepy-3.9.0 urllib3-1.25.10
-----> Discovering process types
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 53.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://twitterbot1k.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added requirements.txt file in your root directory? I faced similar issue when I forgot to add requirements.txt. Please create empty file if you don't need any extra packages. It tells Heroku that your application is written in Python.

Comment: Yes i have that

Comment: I think your application is deployed to Heroku. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Its like a reply bot yet its not working? see min 11:04 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLvMYXKIcPo&t=654s   i think i have to turn the bot on